# Need to create array/json before ajax form submit using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am facing issue in creating json after form submit- I want to send json to ajax call - required json is below

```
{
"person": {
    "firstName": "amr",
    "middleName": "m",
    "lastName": "k",
    "emailId": "amr1@s.in",
    "mobileNumber": "454564333",
    "mobileCountryCode": "+91"
},
"informationSource": [
    {"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}
],
"loginPassword": "password"
}
```

All above fields are in form- I want to submit the form using ajax, below is the code -

```js
var array_data = [];
var password = {
  loginPassword: $('#password').val()
};
var person = {
  firstName: $('#first_name').val(),
  middleName: $('#middle_name').val(),
  lastName: $('#last_name').val(),
  emailId: $('#email').val(),
  mobileNumber: $('#mobile_no').val(),
  mobileCountryCode: $('#country_code').val()
};
var informationSource = [];
$.each($("#hear option:selected"), function() {
  informationSource.push({
    id: $(this).text()
  });
});
array_data.push({
  informationSource: informationSource
});
array_data.push({
  password
});
array_data.push({
  person: person
});
console.log(array_data);

$.ajax({
  url: "api.php",
  type: "POST",
  //dataType: "json",
  data: array_data,
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + acc_token);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('#res-div').css("display:block;");
    $('#signup-div').css("display:none;");
  }
});
```

But this code is not working, This is giving me undefined while pushing array - Please help in creating the required json/array to send through ajax.

Comment: Please show console messages. Why not use `person = $(form).serialize()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to see your HTML, however the main issue you have is that you're pushing multiple objects to an array instead of the target data structure which is an object containing properties. You can also simplify the code slightly by using `map()`. Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  person: {
    firstName: $('#first_name').val(),
    middleName: $('#middle_name').val(),
    lastName: $('#last_name').val(),
    emailId: $('#email').val(),
    mobileNumber: $('#mobile_no').val(),
    mobileCountryCode: $('#country_code').val()
  },
  informationSource: $("#hear option:selected").map(function() {
    return {
      id: $(this).text()
    };
  }).get(),
  loginPassword: $('#password').val()
};

$.ajax({
  url: "api.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: obj,
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + acc_token);
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('#res-div').show();
    $('#signup-div').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
array_data.push({informationSource: informationSource});
array_data.push({password});
array_data.push({person: person});
```

with :

```
var object ={
    person,
    informationSource,
    loginPassword: $('#password').val()
}
array_data.push(object);
```

Comment: password:password is same as just password

Comment: https://prnt.sc/i4c1wl
this is how now my data is created but while i send data using ajax this array is giving me undefined in form data : 
undefined:

Comment: But one thing is that i use JSON.stringify
[{"informationSource":[{"id":"Newspaper"},{"id":"Student"},{"id":"Website"}],"loginPassword":"987456","person":{"firstName":"asdd","middleName":"asd","lastName":"sddd","emailId":"amrish@mailinator.com","mobileNumber":"9874563210","mobileCountryCode":"1"}}]
now i want to remove outer sq. brackets [ ] rest every thing is fine. how can i fix this

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having here is that you are sending an array while jQuery/Ajax/data expects an object.
Instead of sending an array, try doing like this:

```
const array_data = {
    informationSource,
    password,
    person
};
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you need to send one [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```
{
"person": {
    "firstName": "amr",
    "middleName": "m",
    "lastName": "k",
    "emailId": "amr1@s.in",
    "mobileNumber": "454564333",
    "mobileCountryCode": "+91"
},
"informationSource": [
    {"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}
],
"loginPassword": "password"
}
```

And you're trying to send one [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) of objects:

```
[
    {
        "person": {
            "firstName": "amr",
            "middleName": "m",
            "lastName": "k",
            "emailId": "amr1@s.in",
            "mobileNumber": "454564333",
            "mobileCountryCode": "+91"
        }
    },
    {
        "informationSource": [
            {"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}
        ],
    },
    {
        "loginPassword": "password"
    }
]
```

To solve your issue, instead of using [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), set the properties in your object:

```
var loginPassword: $('#password').val();

var person = {
  firstName: $('#first_name').val(),
  middleName: $('#middle_name').val(),
  lastName: $('#last_name').val(),
  emailId: $('#email').val(),
  mobileNumber: $('#mobile_no').val(),
  mobileCountryCode: $('#country_code').val()
};

var informationSource = [];
$.each($("#hear option:selected"), function() {
  informationSource.push({ id: $(this).text() });
});

var data = {
    person : person,
    informationSource : informationSource,
    loginPassword : loginPassword,
}
```